# Using data from picker selections to add entry to parse.com

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform

Trying to input data from pickers into parse.com. This code currently works to input event into parse.com, but you can see I'm using a "string of char" rather than pulling the selection in from the data pickers. When I try to use the variable name ie "events" , gives "use of unknown identifier." Any suggestions as to what should be used to accurately call this selected data to parse?

```
    import UIKit

var eventChoices = [
["5","10","15","30","45","60","90","120","150","180"],
["Hospital Committee","Peer Review","EHR Improvement","Quality Improvement","Business Development"],]

class EventFormViewController: UIViewController,UIPickerViewDataSource,UIPickerViewDelegate{


@IBOutlet weak var eventPicker: UIPickerView!
@IBOutlet weak var eventLabel: UILabel!

func updateLabel(){
    let selectedTime = eventChoices[0][eventPicker.selectedRowInComponent(0)]
    let events = eventChoices[1][eventPicker.selectedRowInComponent(1)]
    eventLabel.text = "Chose \(events) for \(selectedTime) mins"
}

func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int) {
    updateLabel()
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    var user = PFUser.currentUser()
    var event = PFObject(className: "event")
    event.setObject("EHR", forKey: "category")
    event.setObject(8, forKey: "duration")
    event.setObject("Training", forKey: "comment")
    event.setObject(user, forKey: "user")
    event.saveInBackgroundWithBlock {
        (success: Bool!, error: NSError!) -> Void in

        if success == true {
        println("event created")
        }
        else {
        println(error)
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you really tried to use "events", then events is only scoped inside update label and will not be known in viewDidLoad which might explain the error message. I am sure you did not mean that. In the delegate function `didSelectRow`  pick up the picker values based on the component and store them in a variable defined below the class definition so that it is accessible by `viewDidLoad`

You probably expect the pickers to display the strings in eventChoices in each picker of a 2 component picker. The user spins to get the selections of `events` and `selectedTime`. The picker rows are Int. So you would use the `eventChoices` to pick up the right string for the keys `category` and `duration` (as you did in updateLabel, but with compact format if you use the row and component parameters).

The code snippets will look something like this. I am guessing your intent.
Place the variable definitions below `class EventFormViewController: UIViewController,UIPickerViewDataSource,UIPickerViewDelegate{`

```
var events = ""
var selectedTime = ""
```

In `didSelectRow` below `updatelabel()` insert:

```
if component == 0 {
    selectedTime = eventChoices[0][row]
} else if component == 1 {
    events = eventChoices[1][row]
}
```

In `viewDidLoad` insert:

```
event["category"] = events
event["duration"] = selectedTime
```

Note the use of the dictionary-like format which I find convenient.

Use the variables `events` and `category` to create `eventLabel.text` instead of updateLabel()

I think you may want to redesign how you plan to do all this. Usually, the pickers are loaded in `viedDidLoad`. Then you would show the view with the spinner. There would probably a button to initiate the transfer to parse after the user has picked the choices.

Hope this helps.